# Benefits of caching the count of items in a data structure versus on-demand calculation?

Tags: data-structures

Given a data structure, I want to provide an API method `Size` which returns the number of items.

I am vacillating between 2 approaches:

1. Maintain a count and increment/decrement it in response to Add/Delete calls respectively
2. Perform a traversal to calculate the count when `Size` is called.

Approach #2 will take O(n) vs O(1) for approach #1. Other than performance, any other benefits of #1 over #2 ?

Comment: third option: use a dirty bit. mark dirty on modification and recalcuate size on access when it is dirty.

Comment: @BryanChen That is a clever idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By maintaining a separate count, you are running the risk of bugs causing the count to get out of sync with the *actual* number of items in your data structure. Now, if your code is bug-free then this won't be a problem, but you can't guarantee that it will remain bug-free forever (if somebody else comes along and changes something).

I would nearly always choose option #2 unless measurements prove you need to optimise the performance.

Comment: Option #1 also has the potential for bugs, in the traversal code (which will likely be a separate from the traversals necessary to manipulate the data structure.